# Load prototype enhancements with require.js

Tags: javascript, module, requirejs

I am using require.js to load my modules which generally works fine. Nevertheless, I do have two additonal questions:

1) If you have a module that is like a helper class and defines additional methods for existing prototypes (such as `String.isNullOrEmpty`), how would you include them? You want to avoid using the reference to the module.

2) What needs to be changed to use jQuery, too. I understand that jQuery needs to be required but do I also need to pass on `$`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 1) If you have a module that is like a helper class and defines
>   additional methods for existing prototypes (such as
>   String.isNullOrEmpty), how would you include them? You want to avoid
>   using the reference to the module.

If you need to extend prototypes then just don't return a value and use it as your last argument to `require`:

```
// helpers/string.js
define(function() {
    String.prototype.isNullOrEmpty = function() {
        // 
    }
});

// main.js
require(['moduleA', 'helpers/string'], function(moduleA) {

});
```

> 2) What needs to be changed to use jQuery, too. I understand that
>   jQuery needs to be required but do I also need to pass on $?

The only requirement for jQuery is that you configure the path correct

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'path/to/jquery'
    }
});

require(['jquery', 'moduleB'], function($, moduleB) {
    // Use $.whatever
});
```

In my opinion it's unnecessary to use [the version of RequireJS that has jQuery built into it](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html) as this was  primarily used when jQuery didn't support AMD.

Nowadays it does and keeping it separate allows you to swap another library out easily (think Zepto).

Answer (score 0):

2/ For jquery it's really simple :

```
require(["jquery", "jquery.alpha", "jquery.beta"], function($) {
    //the jquery.alpha.js and jquery.beta.js plugins have been loaded.
    $(function() {
        $('body').alpha().beta();
    });
});
```

More information on require site : http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html#get

1/ in my devs for such extension I did it in a global file without require module code.... and I include it in my app with require... not perfect, but it's work fine

**global.js**

```
myglobalvar ="";
(...other global stuff...)
```

**myapp.js**

```
// Filename: app.js
define([
    (...) 
    'metrix.globals'
], function(.....){
myApp = {
(...)
```

Comment: Hi Jean-Michael, let's assume I would like to seperate my html file into three different files: 1 for the html, 1 for jquery (event handling) and 1 for the javascript part. Would you recommend this?

Comment: If you have only 3 files (one of each) I think it would be efficient, not nescessary the best way for doing things, but "efficient way" ;)