# node.js require for Object.prototype?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I'm a bit confused by node.js `require` system.

I know how to `export` or `module.export` function of the `require`d component, but not sure how to enhance js Object with prototype.

For instance, I have a code to enhance js Object with prototype.watch method.

I will have this code in my own npm package, and import with node `require`.

What is the best manner to do this? 
Do I need to refactor this code as a function to export and need to execute after `require`?
Thanks.

```
if (!Object.prototype.watch)
{
    Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "watch",
    {
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: true,
        writable: false,
        value: function(prop, handler)
        {
            var
            oldval = this[prop],
                newval = oldval,
                getter = function()
                {
                    return newval;
                },
                setter = function(val)
                {
                    oldval = newval;
                    return newval = handler.call(this, prop, oldval, val);
                };

            if (delete this[prop])
            { // can't watch constants
                Object.defineProperty(this, prop,
                {
                    get: getter,
                    set: setter,
                    enumerable: true,
                    configurable: true
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

// object.unwatch
if (!Object.prototype.unwatch)
{
    Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "unwatch",
    {
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: true,
        writable: false,
        value: function(prop)
        {
            var val = this[prop];
            delete this[prop]; // remove accessors
            this[prop] = val;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load prototype enhancements with require.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267524/load-prototype-enhancements-with-require-js)

Comment: this is not a dupe of that question, that question is about require.js, which is for the browser.

Comment: @MattGreer My bad will update.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to change objects prototypes in node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329210/where-to-change-objects-prototypes-in-node-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All modules in node.js share the same global scope.

Just `require()` it and any changes you make to global objects will propagate.

Comment: Thank you. Glad to know as simple as that!

Comment: Just keep in mind, if you decide to share your npm package with the world, people won't be happy you're changing global prototypes.

Comment: @Matt Greer , thanks, I understand that. So far, it's just for my own project and not in the public repo.